# Adjacent difference in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

C++ has a handy algorithm std::adjacent_difference which computes the differences between the next/previous of elements of the range.
The Racket implementation is straightforward:

```
(define (adjacent-difference f lst)
    (if(null? (cdr lst))
       '()
       (cons (f (cadr lst)(car lst))
           (adjacent-difference f (cdr lst)))))
```

however we have a lot of handy built-in algorithms inside the Racket so I wanted to reuse them.
The first idea was:

```
(map f (cdr lst) lst)
```

Oops, the sizes of the lists are different, we cannot use map in this way.
I can cheat like this:

```
(map f (append (cdr lst) '(0)) lst)  ; do not use the last element
```

but it is a dirty solution.
Any ideas how to do it without writing a new function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short version:

```
(define (adjacent-difference f xs)
  (for/list ([x xs] [y (cdr xs)])
    (f y x)))
```

Here `x` and `y` runs though the elements of `xs` and `(cdr xs)`
in parallel. Since `(cdr xs)` is the shorter than `xs` the loop
ends when there is no more elements in `(cdr xs)`.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Short solution without writing own function.

Answer (score 2):

In the `map` defined in [SRFI-1 List library](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) different sized lists are allowed with the requirement that at least one is finite. It will only step as many times as the shortest list.

```
#lang racket

;; import map from srfi-1. This shadows the one from racket/base
(require (only-in srfi/1 map))

(define (adjacent-difference f lst)
  (map f (cdr lst) lst))
```

For completeness I'll include the imports needed for the same code to work in Scheme:

```
#!r6rs

(import (except (rnrs) map)
        (only (srfi :1) map))
```

In the next version of Scheme, R7RS, SRFI-1 is the standard list library. Thus this should work in the R7RS "red edition":

```
#!r7rs

(import (scheme)
        (scheme list))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, it isn't only "dirty" but it isn't a solution, since appending the zero at the end means you have more elements than you should. For a three-item list you should only have two differences, right? Or do you always want to pull in default elements?

How about making your own `map`?

```
(define (stalling-map proc . args)
  (if (ormap null? args)
      '()
      (cons (apply proc (map car args))
            (apply stalling-map proc (map cdr args)))))
;;;;
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.12 [3m].
> (let ((lst '(1 3 7 10 11)))
    (stalling-map - (cdr lst) lst))
'(2 4 3 1)
>
```

Comment: "For a three-item list you should only have two differences, right?" - right, "How about making your own map" - in my question I try to avoid it :). I am asking if it is possible to do it using built-in stuff like foldl, foldr etc. Just curious.